# Checking the type of a method parameter

Tags: ruby, types

I am not sure if an object I pass to a method is of the proper type. I might pass a string to a function that can only handle integers. What about some kind of runtime ensurance? I couldn't see a better option than:

```
def someFixNumMangler(input)
  raise "wrong type: integer required" unless input.class == FixNum
  other_stuff
end
```

Any better alternatives?

Comment: I agree with the sentiment. The general approach I espouse is to do the minimal checking required to avoid *weird, unhelpful* errors (or Segfaults when working with C extensions), occurring late when using a library's public API. The kind of defensive programming you get by checking types on all methods is not really practical in Ruby. You can cover some of the gap with tests and documentation, both of which *are* well supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [Kernel#Integer](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) method to convert the input before using it. It will raise an `ArgumentError` when the input could not be converted to an integer in any reasonable fashion.

```
def my_method(number)
  number = Integer(number)
  # do something with number, which is now guaranteed to be an integer
end
```

I recommend Avdi Grimm's new book [Confident Ruby](http://confidentruby.com/) for more insight into this.

Comment: indeed, yet originally (before it was edited) my question was broader, dealing with generic objects. for objects I defined I should write my own method to check...

Comment: Yes, making your own conversion method that handles all conceivable input and raises proper runtime errors is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

If you really need to do type checks, then yes, you only have runtime checking. Code in the question is ok. You can also use `.is_a?`.

```
def someFixNumMangler(input)
  raise "wrong type: integer required" unless input.is_a?(FixNum)
  other_stuff
end
```

The checks may take different forms. If you expect, say, a string and you call string methods on it (`upcase`, `gsub`, etc), the code will blow up if anything other than string is passed. Unless, of course, you pass an object that is not a string, but behaves *just like one* (has the same methods that you call). This is the essence of duck typing.

What if your method looked like this?

```
def someFixNumMangler(input)
  input = input.to_i
  puts "got this: #{input} of #{input.class}"
end


someFixNumMangler(10)
someFixNumMangler('42')
someFixNumMangler(File)

# >> got this: 10 of Fixnum
# >> got this: 42 of Fixnum
# ~> -:2:in `someFixNumMangler': undefined method `to_i' for File:Class (NoMethodError)
# ~>    from -:9:in `<main>'
```

As long as an argument responds to `#to_i`, you don't actually care what its type is.

Comment: I think raising a `TypeError` is more appropriate.

Comment: @toro2k: yes, but that's details